# Why does my FastCGI server application keep getting terminated

Tags: windows, iis, fastcgi

I used libfcgi for Windows to create a FastCGI server app to host the PowerBuilder programming language. It works great when calling from a browser.

When called from a desktop application using WinHTTP, the server exe will terminate after 10-20 requests and a new instance starts. No error message is returned to the desktop app and nothing is written to the Event Viewer. The App Pool (w3wp.exe) does not end, just my exe. My exe is not breaking out of the main loop, it seems to be terminated.

I compiled libfcgi as a DLL without any changes using VS 2022. My C++ server exe calls the FCGI functions in the DLL.

Comment: There is really no need to fight the FastCGI fight, as Microsoft is deprecating its PHP support via FastCGI (search for their PHP 8 announcement for more details) and all IIS FastCGI components are going out of support soon. You will find HttpPlatformHandler a lot easier to integrate, https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpplatformhandler/info

Comment: Where can I find an example of how to write a C++ program that supports that?

Comment: Can you digest the examples listed for HttpPlatformHandler? In short, your C++ program just needs to run as a small HTTP server itself. Then configure it as a new `httpPlatform` in IIS configuration, and pass the desired port `%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%` via command line argument or environment variable.

Comment: `the server exe will terminate after 10-20 requests and a new instance starts.`  If a new instance is started every time it is called, is it possible that the number of calls is too many, resulting in a lot of exe processes, so the system automatically terminates some processes?

Comment: Bruce: No, it is not due to high volume. This happens on my development machine with me clicking a button every 2 or 3 seconds.

Comment: Lex: I am familiar with Winsock in C++ so it looks like I need to write a program that listens for requests and replies with valid HTTP headers followed by the requested data.

Comment: I wrote a program that uses Winsock to listen for requests from HttpPlatformHandler. It seems to be working as expected. I am getting an odd EventLog entry when it first starts up:

        General:
        Recursion too deep; the stack overflowed.
        Details:
        Process '4564' started successfully and is listening on port '17508'.

Any ideas?